# join in Doctrine Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I made 2 table `product` and `category` in Symfony.

I made entity and repository for them.

In product, I have: `id`,`name`,`category`,`discount`,`price`
In category, I have: `id`, `name`, `discount`

I have 2 question here, please help me to solve my problem :

1. in my `product` table my category is int, I use category id from `category` table, I do not know how use join in Symfony , I do many way but every time I failed. Please help me to make join for this tables.
2. I try to read product by Repository but I received category as a number of category table, how can I receive category name instead of category id?

Please help me to solve them.

**Entity/Product.php**

```
class Product implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
     */
    private $category;
```

**Entity/Category.php**

```
class Category implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

Comment: `$category` should not be an integer but `@ORM\ManyToOne`

Comment: "I do not know how use join in Symfony , I do many way but every time I failed." - Please expand your question with what you tried so far?